# How to calculate percentage of a dataframe and add them next to the number with % and inside parenthesis

Tags: r, dplyr, percentage

I think I am having a very easy question but I cannot figure it out or find anything relevant in the website.

I have the following dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(pa = c(1, 1, 1),
                 op = c(1, 2, 5))
```

All these number sum up to 11. What I want is to calculate the percentage of each cell from the sum of 11 and add it next to each cell with the % after and inside a parenthesis.

What i want is something like that:

```
   pa        op       va
1(9.0%)   1(9.0%)   1(9.0%)
1(9.0%)   2(18.1%)  5(45.4%)
```

Thanks.

Comment: i think you might want to look at list columns. https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/nest.html

Answer (score 1):

With `sprintf`:

```r
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(paste0(t(df), sprintf("(%0.1f%%)", t(df)/sum(df)*100)), nrow = 2))
colnames(df) <- c("pa", "op", "va")
df

       pa       op       va
1 1(9.1%)  1(9.1%)  1(9.1%)
2 1(9.1%) 2(18.2%) 5(45.5%)
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much. The dataset I have its much bigger with more columns and rows. I can see that you added the number 11 there. But for me it is not possible to sum all the numbers for each dataset I have as they are too big. Any other way to do it? :)

Comment: You can use `sum(df)`.